# What is the correct way to add an inclusion in the sql query in terms of join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with the following TEST SQL query to get customers count based on a logic + who received a specific email (making sure customer exist in the email sent table)

```
select 
    count(distinct tab1.order_key) as VALUE
from 
    cust_order_type tab1   
inner join 
    cust_membership tab2 on tab1.transaction_id = tab2.transaction_id   
inner join 
    cust_transactions tab3 on tab1.transaction_id = tab3.transaction_id   
                           and tab3.coupon_id not in (123, 456) 
                           ---CHECK IF THEY RECEIVED THE EMAIL    
                           and tab3.customer_key IN (select customer_key from  cust_table tab4  
                                                      where tab4.email in (select email from Email_Sent_Date_List tab5 where tab5.EmailA_Date IS NOT NULL AND tab5.EmailA_Date >= '2020-07-06'))
inner join 
    cust_product_variation tab6 on tab3.product_variation_id = tab6.product_variation_id 
where 
    tab6.country in ('USA', 'CANADA')   
    and tab1.trans_date = '2020-07-06'
```

This query return an output of 600.

The above query has been working but I noticed that the include query logic to check if customer received an email or not exists in the inner join. Talking about this one:

```
---CHECK IF THEY RECEIVED THE EMAIL
and tab3.customer_key IN (select customer_key from  cust_table tab4  where  tab4.email in (select email from Email_Sent_Date_List tab5 where tab5.EmailA_Date IS NOT NULL AND tab5.EmailA_Date >= '2020-07-06'))
```

Now, I am trying to understand and question if that is the correct place for that criteria?

Because, If I move that criteria out of the inner join and add in the end like this:

```
select count(distinct tab1.order_key) as VALUE
from cust_order_type tab1   
inner join cust_membership tab2
    on tab1.transaction_id = tab2.transaction_id   
   inner join cust_transactions tab3    
    on tab1.transaction_id = tab3.transaction_id   
    and tab3.coupon_id not in (123, 456) 
inner join cust_product_variation tab6 
    on tab3.product_variation_id = tab6.product_variation_id 
where tab6.country  IN ('USA','CANADA')   
    and tab1.trans_date  '2020-07-06'
    ---CHECK IF THEY RECEIVED THE EMAIL    
    and tab3.customer_key IN (select customer_key from  cust_table tab4  where  tab4.email in (select email from Email_Sent_Date_List tab5 where tab5.EmailA_Date IS NOT NULL AND tab5.EmailA_Date >= '2020-07-06'))
```

Now this query returns the output of 18000.

The output number is different, how come? Can anyone help me understand this and suggest where is the correct location for this criteria?

**UPDATE**: To test what tables should be or shouldn't be used in the inner join. I tried performing a test.

Where I removed the EMAIL SENT criteria and ran the following query:

```
select count(distinct tab1.order_key) as VALUE
from cust_order_type tab1   
inner join cust_membership tab2
    on tab1.transaction_id = tab2.transaction_id   
   inner join cust_transactions tab3    
    on tab1.transaction_id = tab3.transaction_id   
    and tab3.coupon_id not in (123, 456) 
inner join cust_product_variation tab6 
    on tab3.product_variation_id = tab6.product_variation_id 
where tab6.country  IN ('USA','CANADA')   
    and tab1.trans_date  '2020-07-06'
```

Output: 120000

Now added an inner join with cust table (still without EMAIL SENT  criteria)

```
select count(distinct tab1.order_key) as VALUE
from cust_order_type tab1   
inner join cust_membership tab2
    on tab1.transaction_id = tab2.transaction_id   
   inner join cust_transactions tab3    
    on tab1.transaction_id = tab3.transaction_id   
    and tab3.coupon_id not in (123, 456) 
inner join cust_product_variation tab6 
    on tab3.product_variation_id = tab6.product_variation_id

INNER JOIN cust_table tab4
ON tab3.customer_key = tab4.customer_key
 
where tab6.country  IN ('USA','CANADA')   
    and tab1.trans_date  '2020-07-06'
```

Same Output: 120000

Please let me know if this helps in understanding how cust table should be correctly used in addition to email sent criteria?

Comment: They are completely different things, the first is a join condition which determines whether a row in another table should be joined on. The second is a where condition, which determines whether the row should end up in the resultset. If you add a join condition which is nothing to do with the table being joined, such as what you have done here, you will get totally wrong results. a join condition should only **ever** contain the logic to match the row from the table being joined.

Comment: Thank you @DaleK for your comment. If I am following you correctly, the 2nd query is correct if I am trying to get customer count on the logic + if they have received the email by checking the existence of a row in email sent table. Is that correct?

Comment: Hi @DaleK In my case, technically I do not need to join cust_table but the only reason I need it because I want to check if customer record is in email sent table and email sent table only connects with cust_table via email address. In order words, I need to add an intermediate table cust_table to be able to check criteria in email sent. Please let me know if this makes sense? and what is your suggestion?

Comment: Why are you using `and tab3.customer_key in (select ...)` ?  - Just use a regular join.

Comment: Hi @Bohemian thank for your question. I just explained the usage of that criteria in my above comment

Comment: Hi @Bohemian I just performed a text and added the information as an UPDATE to the question above. Please let me know if that helps?

Comment: To verify your logic use an `EXCEPT` statement to compare the queries and inspect some of the records that appear in 1 query and not another. Its all very well thinking you have the logic correct, but nothing beats verifying it or calculating it a second way for peace of mind.

Comment: You keep asking what is the *correct* way? There is no right and wrong. If no error occurs, then ***you*** have to define the desired results. Only ***you*** can decide what is the *correct* output. Does the original 600 rows fit your end use (app/report) needs? Or 18,000? Or something else? Are there duplicate, extraneous information, missing columns, rows, incorrect distinct counts, etc.? Again, this is criteria only ***you*** can specify and ideally show us the issue [with data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/1422451).

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Hi @Parfait Yes - I agree with you. I was just trying to get some feedback for me to understand the logic. You are 100% correct. Regarding the aliases, the above query is for testing only for sharing which is why I used not the best alias. But I see what you are trying to explain.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** For anyone who is looking for a similar answer or just trying to understand the logic.

In my case, query1 is giving the expected result (compared to the query2 result which is giving more count than how many contacts actually exist in the EMAIL SENT table).

By keeping the logic same of query1, I ended up updating it slightly (which is giving me exact same result as before)

Here is my working updated query1 (giving same result as before which is an expected output compared to query2):

```
select count(distinct tab1.order_key) as VALUE
from cust_order_type tab1   
inner join cust_membership tab2
    on tab1.transaction_id = tab2.transaction_id   
   inner join cust_transactions tab3    
    on tab1.transaction_id = tab3.transaction_id   
    and tab3.coupon_id not in (123, 456)
inner join cust_table tab4 
on tab3.customer_key = tab4.customer_key
inner join Email_Sent_Date_List tab5
on tab4.email = tab5.email       
    and (select email from Email_Sent_Date_List tab5 where tab5.EmailA_Date IS NOT NULL AND tab5.EmailA_Date >= '2020-07-06')  ---CHECK IF THEY RECEIVED THE EMAIL 
inner join cust_product_variation tab6 
    on tab3.product_variation_id = tab6.product_variation_id 
where tab6.country  IN ('USA','CANADA')   
    and tab1.trans_date  '2020-07-06'
```

Comment: I wonder about your subquery use. You overwrite `tab5` alias, so that subquery may always return `TRUE`. What happens if you replace entire subquery as `AND 1=1`. Also the very last condition should raise syntax error: `and tab1.trans_date  '2020-07-06'`.

Comment: In fact, your `AND (subquery)` should throw an error `An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected near ')'`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adjusting the specific `JOIN` to a more compact and clear logic:

```
inner join Email_Sent_Date_List tab5
    on  tab4.email = tab5.email       
    and tab5.EmailA_Date IS NOT NULL      -- CHECK IF THEY RECEIVED THE EMAIL 
    and tab5.EmailA_Date >= '2020-07-06'  -- CHECK IF THEY RECEIVED THE EMAIL
```

In fact, you may not need any outer `WHERE` clause given all joins are `INNER JOIN` and `WHERE` can be considered an implicit `JOIN`. See fuller adjustment with more useful aliases.

```
select count(distinct o.order_key) as [VALUE]
from cust_order_type o   
inner join cust_membership m
    on o.transaction_id = m.transaction_id   
    and o.trans_date = '2020-07-06'        -- MOVED FROM WHERE TO ON
inner join cust_transactions t    
    on o.transaction_id = t.transaction_id   
    and t.coupon_id not in (123, 456)
inner join cust_table c 
    on t.customer_key = c.customer_key
inner join Email_Sent_Date_List e
    on c.email = e.email       
    and e.EmailA_Date IS NOT NULL          -- CHECK IF THEY RECEIVED THE EMAIL 
    and e.EmailA_Date >= '2020-07-06'      -- CHECK IF THEY RECEIVED THE EMAIL 
inner join cust_product_variation p 
    on t.product_variation_id = p.product_variation_id 
    and p.country IN ('USA','CANADA')      -- MOVED FROM WHERE TO ON
```